# Set system properties from lifts Props object

Tags: java, scala, lift

I have a java library that I access from my lift project. The java library needs some system properties. I would have thought the values in the Props object would automactially be available as system properties but this does not seem to be the case. Can someone tell me the best way to set all the properties so that my java library can access them?

I guess it would be something along the lines of

```
System.setProperties(Props.???)
```

Thanks
Des

Comment: Did you try your guess? It's not clear exactly where you're stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do it is to add the following line to my Boot class:

```
Props.props.foreach((p) => System.setProperty(p._1, p._2))
```

Comment: That works, but makes everything a system property. If you only need a few items - why not set them explicitly in `Boot.scala` or at least by filtering the `Props.props` map? I suppose there's not much of an issue in setting everything, but my personal preference would be to only globally set what is necessary.